# How do I use Font awesome Icon in React?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I want to use fontAwesome icons in ReactJs. I have not done this before. I want to do something like home Icons as well as Signout Icons in React.

Here is what I have done so far.

I included the font awesome Lib

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

Now I want to use in the application Like so

```
                        <td width="150px">
                        <p align="center"/>
                        <button className="btn"><i className='icon-home'></i></button>
                        </td>
                        <td width="135">
                            <p align="center"/>
                        <button className="btnSignout"><i className='fa fa-home'></i></button>
                        </td>
```

How do I use FontAwesome in React Application?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)? They make it pretty clear.

Answer (score 4):

To use `Font Awesome` in the react project, you should have to -

1. install the following packages (run the following commands in the terminal)

`npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`

`npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`

`npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome`

2. Now it's time to call and use into the JavaScript file.

import into the file the following 2 lines.

`import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";`

`import { faMugHot } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

The format of using icon is as follow,

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faIconName, faAnotherIconName} />`

for Example: `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAnchor, faMugHot} />

`Note:` icon name will be camelcase `fa<IconName>`. for example, in the font-awesome website font name is `fa-anchor` we can write it as `faAnchor`. for long name of the icon, if the name is `fa-mug-hot` we have to write it as `faMugHot`.

Answer (score 1):

**To use font awesome icons in easy way  into your React project use react-icon library which not only provides support for font awesome but as well as provides for Bootstrap icons , Heroicons and more.**

**Step 1.** npm install react-icons --save

**step 2.** Import a icon like this -

```js
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
```

**Note**: FaBeer is icon name here for more icons visit to [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons)

**Step 3.** Use it something like this -

```js
class Question extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h3> Lets go for a <FaBeer />? </h3>
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a different library. React-Icons is a more comprehensive icon source than React-FontAwesome, which only provides FA icons and has different syntax.

Comment: @isherwood although it's comprehensive but easier to implement.

Comment: I agree--it's what I use. But the question clearly references the other. Mostly I wanted to point that out to anyone who might attempt to use your syntax with the other library. That won't work. I suggest making that clear in your answer.

Comment: How can one use this in Button ?

Comment: for example search icon in a button import it something like this -  import {FaSearchengin} from "react-icons/fa"   and use it something like this  <button>submit <FaSearchengin/> </button>

Comment: I hope you got the point!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, check below code or click here for  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/font-awesome-cqztjo?file=Hello.js)

**Please double check the libraries I used and install**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Please check this</p>

        <button className="btn btn-primary">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size={'1x'} />
          <span style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}> My Button</span>
        </button>

        <br />
        <br />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} size={'2x'} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Um, how do i implement in Button is what i asked.

Comment: sorry for confusion, please check again I updated the code and demo link as well.

Comment: @Blaq, it doesn't matter what element or component it's inside. It works the same. Also, saying "um" comes across as sarcastic and unprofessional. Maybe it's a cultural difference.

Comment: @stackoverflow, your solution worked. I thank you <3

Comment: Good to accept and upvote an answer if that solved your problem.